# XML bindings for Microsoft XMLLite

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, xsd, xmllite

I have a C++ project in which I am using [Microsoft XmlLite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752838) for parsing several XML files. Now I have a new file that I need to parse and I have an XSD schema for it. I know there are many C++ XML binding tools out there, but all I have found so far require me to include yet another XML parsing library, which I would like to avoid. Hence my question: is there any open source or commercial tool that generates C++ XML bindings based on Microsoft XmlLite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CodeSynthesis](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/c++/tree/) seems to be the closest tool which will provide in-memory XML data binding to integrate with XMLLite.

> The C++/Tree mapping generates C++ classes that represent data types defined in XML Schema, a set of parsing functions that convert XML documents to a tree-like in-memory object model, and a set of serialization functions that convert the object model back to XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Could you please let me know where you found the information that this product support XmlLite? I was not able to find any reference to XmlLite on their website.

Comment: It generates C++ XML bindings without the use of a parser. XMlLite has a [customizable XML reader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms752863), CodeSynthesis has a [customizable generated type system](http://wiki.codesynthesis.com/Tree/Customization_guide).

Comment: I see, so I would need to write the code for setting the values of each node and attribute that I get from XmlLite into the objects generated by CodeSynthesis. Am I right?

Comment: Correct, you would write the glue between the two programs.